# Implementing saved python regression model to react expo application

Tags: python, react-native, linear-regression, mobile-application

I have a python regression model that predicts one's level of happiness based on user-input data, i have trained and tested it using Python.
But I'm using React Native to create my mobile application.

My mobile application will take in the user-input data needed and will output a prediction on their level of happiness. Anyone has an idea on how to implement this? Any advice would be appreciated! I lack the experience, but have an interest in this area, Im still learning so please help me out :)

Comment: How and where are you saving your model? is it a pickle file?

Comment: What kind of model is it? If the model is a linear/logistic regression model, you could simply save the vector of weights/coefficients per feature to a file, e.g. `{'x0': 3.5, 'x1': 0.9, ...}`, load that into a key-value mapping in JS, and do the prediction in base JS instead of doing something more complicated like developing an entire ML API in Python for such a simple operation.

Comment: Hi @Avinash , I saved it as tensorflow lite.

Comment: @blacksite - it is a mulitple linear regression model.. but the model will not be re-evaluated again?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create python API and call it from the mobile application by passing the input features. Python API will return you the forecasted value. This API will load the regression model and make a forecast on given input features. I hope It will help.

Comment: Hi @jennyfer, Is my answer is helpful? Do you need any other help here?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this! do i need to make use of firebase in that case?